# AJAX with ASP.NET: How to call a method of a user control using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, user-controls

I have a master page that has a placeholder to generate the content for `Default.aspx`
 `Default.aspx` defines a `User Control`:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <uc:maincontent ID="maincontent" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

`User Control` has the following code inside:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Get Data" runat="server" data-toggle="model" data-target="#myModal" title="Provide a Year"
            ID="btnGenerate" />
</div
```

Then, I want to call a method, defined in `User Control` code behind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GeneratePdfs()
{
    string test = "Test String";
    return test;
}
```

To do that I have the following `jQuery` code:

```
$('#btnGenerate').click(function () {

    if (!ValidateInput()) {
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "????"
        .....
    });
```

I have also created a `Generic Handler` with the following code. I found this example on stackoverflow

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    using (var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {
        Page pageHolder = new Page();
        var control = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl("~/controls/maincontent.ascx");
        pageHolder.Controls.Add(control);
        context.Server.Execute(pageHolder, writer, false);
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        context.Response.Write(writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
    }
}
```

But this example does not explain how to call a `Web Method` defined in my `User Control`.

What is the right way to accomplish something like that?

Comment: You're going about this in a bad way. Abstract the logic that the user controls into a method that the user control can call and that your AJAX handler can call. AJAX and Web Forms controls don't mix that well.

Comment: What is a better way then? Should I use `Update Panel` with ASP.NET AJAX? Or should I just create a simple `html` page and do not use ASPX pages at all?

Comment: Dear lord no, don't use an UpdatePanel ever. ASPX is fine, but your AJAX call should not depend on manipulating the controls.

Comment: And what should I do then. Do not use a `User Control` and put its content into `Default.aspx` page directly and then call AJAX from there?

Comment: Think about what it is that your AJAX control should accomplish. Does that logic really make sense to be a user control?

Comment: I might use that control a few more times with other pages. That's why I needed it.

Comment: But the control itself should not be performing the action is my point. Your logic should be abstracted out to a standalone class. Then your controller and your generic handler can both make use of that abstracted logic.